# Removing all zero-values except for those flanking non-zero values

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

Given a vector of:

```
a = [0;0;2;3;0;2;10;11;0;0;0;4;5;8;0;0;0]
```

Can anybody show or suggest a way to remove all zero-values except for those which flank non-zero values?

The desired result for the above would be:

```
b = [0;2;3;0;2;10;11;0;0;4;5;8;0]
```

Where these values have been removed:

[**0**;0;2;3;0;2;10;11;0;**0**;0;4;5;8;0;**0**;**0**]

I'm not sure where to start with this problem without having to resort to using a set of IF statements such as:

```
for k=1:length(a)
    if a(k) == 0 && a(k+1) == 0
        *delete value*
    end
    if a(k) == 0 && a(k+1) >0
        *keep/store value*
    end
    if a(k) > 0
        *keep/store value*
    end
    if a(k) == 0 && a(k-1) >0
        *keep/store value*
    end
end
```

And so forth.

Comment: you can use `diff` if none of your non-zero numbers comes in pairs - Otherwise you can still use `diff` (just more intelligently). I just realized, if there are consecutive zeros you only want to remove 1?

Comment: Any zero value that has a non-zero value immediately to the left or right of it is kept - the rest are removed. If there are 3 or more consecutive zeroes then at least 1 will be removed, for example [4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10] - the output would simply be: [4, 8, 0, 0, 10] - the two zeros that fit the above criteria are kept.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann In case you're interested in golfed solutions to your problem, [see here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89188/keep-nonzeros-and-their-neighbours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create two additional vectors, one shifting to the left, one to the right from your vector `a` (**EDIT** : using `circshift` as suggested in the comments below) :

```
a       = [0;0;2;3;0;2;10;11;0;0;0;4;5;8;0;0;0];
a_right = circshift(a,-1);
a_left  = circshift(a,1);
```

Create a matrix M :

```
M = [a,a_right,a_left];
```

And sum each line :

```
s = sum(M,2);
```

Then find the components that differs from 0 :

```
i = find(s~=0);
```

This will give you the right indexes to select from your initial vector :

```
b=a(i)
```

I get :

```
b=[0;2;3;0;2;10;11;0;0;4;5;8;0]
```

Comment: you might want to replace `a_right` with `circshift(a,-1)` and `a_left` with `circshift(a,1)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [convolution](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
b = a(conv(abs(sign(a)), ones(3,1), 'same')>0);
```

This works as follows:

1. Convert `a` to a vector of zeros or ones (`abs(sign(a))`), with zero if the entry of `a` is zero and one otherwise.
2. Convolve with a mask of three ones (`conv(..., ones(3,1), 'same')`). So a nonzero value in `a` produces a nonzero result at its position and at its neighbouring positions.
3. This is compared with zero to create a logical vector with which `a` is indexed (`a(...>0)`).

This can be easily **generalized** to keep **more distant neighbours**. Specifically, use the mask `ones(2*N+1,1)` to keep zero values that are up to `N` entries away of nonzero values.

Answer (score 6):

I have another idea (granted, not very different from the other two), using logical indexing:

```
a(~(~a & ~[diff(a);0] & ~[0;diff(a)] ));
```

Explanation:

- `~` - boolean `not`, returns a boolean value representing the "opposite" of the input.
- `~a` - returns the zero elements of `a` (it is not required in the example you gave, but is important if you have repeating nonzero values that you would like to keep).
- `~[diff(a);0] & ~[0;diff(a)]` - return the values whose derivative on either size is zero.
- `a(~(...))` - return the values of `a` that aren't "zeros with the same values on both sides", which is `b`.

---

Another way to write the same thing (using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and exploiting the "truthiness" of nonzero values):

```
a( a | [diff(a);0] | [0;diff(a)] );
```

You can think of it as finding "*which values to **keep***" rather than "*which values to **remove***", where the simplest way I can think of to define which values to keep is "all nonzero elements *and* zero elements that have a nonzero on either side".